# Bootstrap CSS not working on elements created with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am adding div:s with vanilla javascript to a page stylized with Bootstrap. All elements hardcoded in the Html is working fine with Bootstrap. The elements added with javascript comes up without any bootstrap-style. Although from the dev-tab I can see that all the elements have the exact proper Bootstrap-classes attached to them.

Example code:

```
var masterDiv = document.getElementById('master')
var divName = document.createElement('div')
divName.setAttribute('class', 'row')
var divLeftMarg = document.createElement('div')
divLeftMarg.setAttribute('class', 'col-md-2 margin')
divName.appendChild(divLeftMarg)
var divNameSub = document.createElement('div')
divNameSub.setAttribute('class', 'col-md-8 name')
divNameSub.innerHTML = thisData.firstname + " " + thisData.lastname
divName.appendChild(divNameSub)
var divRightMarg = document.createElement('div')
divRightMarg.setAttribute('class', 'col-md-2 margin')
masterDiv.appendChild(divName)
```

I saw a suggestion as an answer to an old question and tried the solution, to change it into:

```
divNameSub.className += ' col-md-8 name'
```

This didn't work, however.

Any suggestions what to try?

Comment: Your code generates rows with columns that match Bootstrap's classes. What's missing when you view it? Are you not wrapping it all in a .container?

Comment: The master div everything is appended to is of class container-fluid. The other elements within that div - hardcoded, not added by javascript - works great with bootstrap. Missing is all bootstrap-characteristics - the grid, style etc.

Comment: Can you post the generated code (use console to find it, right click, copy outer html)?